School Teacher looking for help adding 3d Rigged Models to curriculum
I teach 7th & 8th graders who are looking to graduate from 2D Adobe Animate into 3d character rigs.  Because we're just an exploratory class, I'm looking for a handful of pre-rigged characters that the kids can explore with in class on Blender 4.02.  Our school district won't go back to a previous version where we could use Mixamo, which is a shame.  Can anyone offer any places that have free 3d rigged animations that would work for this project?  Thanks in advance for reading and any help!

there seem to be fixes for the add-on: https://www.blendernation.com/2024/03/10/mixamo-addon-fix-for-blender-4-0-and-beyond/ (i didn't test) and you can still import them "manually" from mixamo to Blender...so where is the problem?

The Mixamo addon fix (which I'm using successfully in Blender 4.1.1) is also described here.

go to mixamo page -> choose an animation -> download as fbx
go to Blender -> import fbx -> choose your downloaded fbx
Done.
